# Mac Notifications Center keeps hijacking swipe left scrolling

Tags: notifications, trackpad, macos

I'm just trying to scroll left using my trackpad while in other apps and the notifications center consistently takes over control of my screen like it thinks I am trying to pull it out into visibility. Nevermind that my cursor is nowhere near the right edge of the screen.

How do I completely disable this functionality? It is really interfering with my ability to effectively navigate other apps that depend on horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default gesture for [Notification Center on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/notification-center-mchl2fb1258f/mac) is:

> swipe left with two fingers from the right edge of the trackpad

Is it possible that you use two fingers while trying to scroll?

You can disable this gesture in System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures by unticking Notification Center